# File paths right by me and phpStorm but wrong in real world

Tags: php, path, phpstorm, relative-path

phpStorm and I agreee this is crazy but "wrong" file paths work while "right" ones fail. Basic structure.

```
  |
  |------classes(directory)
  |         |
  |         |
  |         Person.php
  |
  |------include(directory)
  |         |
  |         |
  |         db-connect.inc.php
  |         autoloader.inc.php
  |         helper.inc.php
  |
  |
  |index.php
  |etc.php
```

In index I use: (1)

```
include_once "include/autoloader.inc.php";
include_once "include/db-connect.inc.php";
include_once "include/helper.inc.php";
```

and in Person.php I would expect to use: (2)

```
include_once "../include/autoloader.inc.php";
include_once "../include/db-connect.inc.php";
include_once "../include/helper.inc.php";
```

But that gets is:

```
"Warning: include_once(../include/autoloader.inc.php): failed to open stream:
No such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\dummy\classes\Person.php on line 2"
```

Bizarely (3)

```
include_once "/../include/autoloader.inc.php";
include_once "/../include/db-connect.inc.php";
include_once "/../include/helper.inc.php";
```

works and even more bizarely so does (4)

```
include_once "include/autoloader.inc.php";
include_once "include/db-connect.inc.php";
include_once "include/helper.inc.php";
```

even though we are up one directory level!

phpStorm flags 3 and 4 as errors (says "Path include/autoloader.inc.php not found" and "Include expression is not resolved") while (2), which is what I thought was "right", gets a nice big green tick but fails at debug or if directly accessed via http://localhost etc.

I always struggle with these path things but how come phpStorm and I agree and the real world say nope!

Guess I will have to put `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` in all over the place (lot easier with Storm instead of longhand!) but still a pain!

Comment: Your folder name is 'includes' in your directory tree example, but your include statement says 'include' - is there a typo in your code or example?

Comment: You may want to try getcwd from the including php file to see if it thinks you are where you think you are. http://php.net/manual/en/function.getcwd.php

Comment: Try using more like absolute paths, e.g. `include_once __DIR__ . "/../include/autoloader.inc.php";` -- much more reliable as in this way you are not giving chance for PHP to misinterpret it (e.g. because you may have complex `include_path` etc). Ideally I would recommend to use classes, PSR-4 and class autoloading -- in such case only few include/require and the rest will be loaded automatically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is correct behaviour.

The page you loaded is in `/`

There you included a file from `/includes`

And now the file you have included is part of the page in `/`

So all includes in the included file are seen as relatives from `/` not from `/includes`

and so on...

Comment: There are two different pages - one in root the other in classes. I do not see how the include should be using the same path.

Comment: When you inlcude a file in a page the included file becomes part of the page and references to the directory tree from within a page are related to the page position in the tree and not from the position of any eventual included file.